# Recursive ngInclude

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm working on a web app which i have to personalize by loading a custom theme (this means a bunch of html files, each of them having many js/css files as dependencies) from the disk based on the location url. Since my project already uses AngularJs, i figured out that i can use ngInclude to load each html component in my application.

Although the include works succesfully, the js and css imports of the loaded page are not imported (which is pretty bad since i have hundreds of those, and it's really hard to add them manually at the beginning).

My question is: can i ngInclude recursively the wanted page and all its dependencies? If it's not possible, is there any workaround to be used? Can this be done using other framework than AngularJs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for that extended project I'd strongly recommend RequireJS, it might take you some time at first, but then the code will be more flexible and maintainable which will save you tons of time

http://requirejs.org/